# How to find out the total time spent in a particular module?

Tags: python

Basically I want to find out, on a given function call how much time was spent within a particular module, including subcalls to functions in other modules as well. Any suggestion on how to achieve such a thing?

For example:

```
# foo.py

import bar

@time(bar)
def foo():

    ...
    bar.qux()
    ...
    bar.foobar()
```

---

```
# bar.py
import foofoo
import barbar

def qux():

    ...
    foofoo.foo()
    ...

def foobar():

    ...
    barbar.bar()
    ...
```

Call to `foo` in `foo.py` should return the total time spent inside the `bar` module(`bar.py`), which in the above case should include time spent inside `barbar` and `foofoo`.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is a profiler. Read here for more:

[How can you profile a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Answer (score -1):

python

```
import timeit
help (timeit)
```